# Showing a hidden UITabBArController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am hiding the UITabBar controller using the code below.

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
```

This is working fine.But when I return back how can I show the bar which is already hidden?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the code I provided above I used this

```
details.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
```

ie replaced self with details.

THanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Add a delegate property to the details viewController with a method that you call before leaving the details view and unhide the bottom bar in there?